# Compare a date with an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a user defined function for a CHECK constraint in a music database, in which the songyear (int) of a song has to be greater than or equal to the startdate (date) of the artist who records that song. i.e the song has to be recorded after or in the same year the artist began their career. This is what I have so far:

create function dbo.IsSongYearGreaterThanStartDate()
returns int
as
begin

```
    declare @result int
if(select count(*) from artist a, song s
    where a.artistname = s.artistname and 
    s.songyear >=  a.startdate) = (select count(*) from 
    artist a2, song s2 where a2.artistname = s2.artistname)

    set @result = 1
else 
    set @result = 0

return @result
```

end

But the data types are incompatible. How do I compare them?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Evolve. NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the year, then extract it from the date:

```
s.songyear >= year(a.startdate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was not aware of this function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help :

```
declare @result int
if(select count(*) from artist a, song s
    where a.artistname = s.artistname and 
    s.songyear >=   DATEPART(year,a.startdate)) = (select count(*) from 
    artist a2, song s2 where a2.artistname = s2.artistname)

    set @result = 1
else 
    set @result = 0

return @result
```

but if I understand your requirement it's better to change you script to check this, because your query is not optimize.

I changed your script but I'm not sure match your requirement.

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT CheckResult FROM(
    SELECT 
     CASE WHEN(s.songyear >= DATEPART(YEAR,MIN(startdate) over(partition by a.artistname))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CheckResult
    FROM song s
    INNER JOIN artist a on s.artistname = a.artistname
) result
WHERE result.CheckResult = 0)
    RETURN 0
ELSE
    RETURN 1
```

This query is more efficient

Comment: @MikeVandervelden I added an alternative query. please check if it's ok

Comment: Yes this is good, thank you, though the join will have to be uncommented and replaced with an inner join.

Comment: I changed my answer and add inner join and omit `#` from beginning  of tables name, `#` before tables name is temp table it was just for my test and if you don't use any prefix before `join` it means `inner join`